# reusable method signature in d.ts file

Tags: typescript

How does one create a reusable method signature

```
declare module "mymodule" {

export function foo1(x: string, y: number): any;
export function foo2(x: string, y: number): any;
export function foo3(x: string, y: number): any;

}
```

I can create an interface

```
interface IFoo {
    (x: string, y: number): any;
}
```

But I can not do:

```
export function foo: IFoo
```

at least not in this manner, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but you can do :

```
let bar : IFoo;
bar = foo;
```

and this will be syntactically correct. You don't need export the type when you export the function. But where you import it, you can assign the function to any interface typed variable.

[Here is a simple playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20IFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(x%3A%20string%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20a(x%3A%20string%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22hi%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20b%3A%20IFoo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ab%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A)